# Date cannot be serialized or deserialized

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to serialize and deserialize **Nullable** DateTime to/from JSON but I do not want to annotate it with [JsonConverterAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm). However, I would like to keep it at once place in [JsonSerializerSettings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm) not bloating DTOs with those attributes keeping DTOs clean as usual.

**Here is DTO:**

```
public class Post
{
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is [Custom JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm):**

```
internal class EpochDateTimeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var t = (long)Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value.ToString());
        return t.FromUnixTime();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        long ticks;
        DateTime valueAsDate = (DateTime)value;
        if (valueAsDate != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                var epoc = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                var delta = (valueAsDate) - epoc;
                if (delta.TotalSeconds < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unix epoc starts January 1st, 1970");
                }
                ticks = (long)delta.TotalSeconds;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Expected date object value.");
            }
            writer.WriteValue(ticks);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the minimal repro:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace NameSpaceSample
{
  public class Post
  {
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
  }

  public class Program
  {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
         {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
               new EpochDateTimeConverter()
            }
         };

         string postAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Post { Created = DateTime.UtcNow }, settings);

         Console.WriteLine(postAsJson);// {"Created":"2015-09-17T17:15:06.6160689Z"}

         var json = "{\"Created\":1442510191}";

         Post post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(json, settings);//Exception here

         Console.ReadKey();
       }
    }
}
```

The exception thrown at that line is:

```
JsonReaderException: 
Error reading date. Unexpected token: Integer. Path 'Created', line 1, position 21.
```

**NOTE:**

I know this can be resolved by just annotating it with [JsonConverterAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) as below but I don't want to do that for aforementioned reason.

```
public class Post
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(EpochDateTimeConverter))]
  public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Note that the Unix epoch is in terms of UTC, but a given `DateTime` could be in terms of local, utc, or some other unspecified time zone (see `DateTimeKind`).  Unless you're absolutely certain all of your `DateTime` values are in terms of UTC, then I wouldn't use this approach.  The best practice for dates in JSON is to use ISO8601, which is already provided by JSON.net.

Comment: @MattJohnson I am aware of that. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own. I just had to change `CanConvert` function to following:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
   return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
}
```

It is not very easy to find out. Putting my answer here to help others if they ever face this.

Answer (score 0):

I give you my way from any object to another object so that you don't worry transfer anything ,thanks

```
  public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object value)
        {
            T returnValue = default(T);

            if (value is T)
            {
                returnValue = (T)value;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    returnValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException)
                {
                    returnValue = default(T);
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CanConvert(Type objectType)` method of the `JsonConverter` determines if that converter will be used for the current property that is being serialized/deserialized.

As the type of your property is `DateTime?` and that is not assignable from `DateTime` it returns false and the converter is then not being used.

You just need to change the method to the following:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return typeof(DateTime?).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
}
```